# Persisting a Map where the Key is an Entity with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

New to Hibernate and I want to persist a hashmap where the key is another entity. I've gone through a number of online articles and similar questions and all of them produce some form of IllegalStateException.

Here is what I have currently:

```java
@Entity
public class SecondClass extends DomainObject {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany ( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyClass ( MyEntity.class )
    private final Map<MyEntityClass, Integer> myMap;
}
```

I am too inexperienced at Hibernate to know what the problem is or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the JPA WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Map_Key_Columns_(JPA_2.0)), you might need to use `@MapKeyJoinColumn` to specify the column that's used to join two entities. I also don't think you want both `@OneToMany` and `@ElementCollection` for the same relationship.

For example, this should work:

```java
@Entity
public class SecondClass extends DomainObject {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "MY_ENTITY_ID")
    private final Map<MyEntityClass, Integer> myMap;
}
```

Comment: This produces a new IllegalStateException: "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"

Comment: Is one of the keys (instance of MyEntityClass) new and not yet saved?

Comment: You might try it with `@OneToMany` (with the cascading as in your original code), the documentation isn't totally clear about it.

Comment: What approach should one prefer? Making a `MyEntityClassWithNumber` that would wrap `MyEntityClass` and `Integer` and using a `Set<MyEntityClassWithNumber>` inside `SecondClass`, vs using the `Map` like in your answer?

Comment: Hello! I've had a very similar question recently - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77848922/4759176. I've been told that it's simply not possible to use `Map<MyEntityClass, Integer>`, because `the entities on the far side must appear as the values in the map, not the keys`. Yet your answer uses it? I'm so very confused and would greatly appreciate any advice!