# Hibernate, Spring Data: Map for storing a key-value OneToMany vs a separate entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Suppose I have an entity `Dog`, and an entity `Person`. A `Dog` assigns a 1-10 points of loyalty to each Person it knows.

Which approach is better to use:

Store the person-loyalty data in a `Map`:

```
@Entity(name = "dogs")
public class Dog  {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "person_loyalty_mapping", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "dog_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private Map<Person, Integer> loyalties;
}
```

Or create a new entity:

```
@Entity(name = "person_loyalty")
public class PersonLoyalty  {
  ...
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Person person;
  @Column
  private Integer loyalty;
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "dogs")
public class Dog  {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<PersonLoyalty> loyalties;
}
```

Which approach is more efficient and more often used (assuming there would be at most 100 key-value pairs in the map, so that the cost of accessing a value by key should be negligible)?

**EDIT**:

**Dog.java**

```
@Entity(name = "dogs")
public class Dog  {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dog_sequence",
        sequenceName = "dog_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "dog_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "dog_person_loyalties", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dog_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    @Column(name = "loyalty")
    private Map<Person, Integer> loyalties;
...
```

Results in tables: `dogs`, `dog_person_loyalties`:

[image]

*The second approach*:

**Cat.java**:

```
@Entity(name = "cats")
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cat_sequence",
        sequenceName = "cat_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "cat_sequence")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cat")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Map<Person, CatPersonLoyalty> loyalty;
...
```

**CatPersonLoyalty.java**:

```
@Entity
public class CatPersonLoyalty  {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cat_person_sequence",
        sequenceName = "cat_person_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "cat_person_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cat_id")
    private Cat cat;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person person;

    private int loyalty;
...
```

results in tables: `cats`, `cat_person_loyalty`:

[image]

So the only difference I see is that `cat_person_loyalty` has an `id` (due to it corresponding to an `Entity`). While the `dog_person_loyalties` has a composite primary key: `(dog_id, person_id)`.

However, I still don't see why the second approach would be preferable to the first one. Why would I need to know an ID of a person-loyalty pair? How would going with the first approach could potentially adversely affect performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped relationships have an entity type on each end.  When mapped on one side as a `Map`, the entities on the other side are the *values* of that map, not its keys.  That rules out your first alternative.

Note also that in order for *each* dog to assign a loyalty score to each person it knows, you need either a many-to-many relationship or you need the persons to be partitioned among the dogs, so that no two dogs both have a loyalty score for the same person.

But you have not just a many-to-many, but one in which each pair of related entities has additional data associated with that relationship.  That extra data does not belong exclusively to any dog or person, so you need an entity for it.  Now your relationship graph looks like this:

```
Dog  <-- 1:many -->  DogPersonLoyalty  <-- many:1 -->  Person
```

On the `Dog` side, the mapped relationship is 1 `Dog` to many `DogPersonLoyalty`.  You can map it as a `Set<DogPersonLoyalty>` as you suggest, but also as a `List<DogPersonLoyalty>` or, yes, a `Map<some_key_type, DogPersonLoyalty>`.  There are advantages and disadvantages to each.

If you wanted to do it as a `Map`, then that might look like so:

```
@Entity
public class DogPersonLoyalty  {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="dog_id")
  private Dog dog;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
  private Person person;

  private int loyalty;
}

@Entity
public class Dog  {
  // ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="dog")
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="person_id")
  private Map<Person, DogPersonLoyalty> loyalty;
}
```

Note: I've limited the annotations and annotation parameters to a minimal relevant set.  I think it's all good, but you might need more to serve your full needs.

> Which approach is more efficient and more often used (assuming there would be at most 100 key-value pairs in the map, so that the cost of accessing a value by key should be negligible)?

It depends a lot on how it would be used.  If the database is as small as you say, then chances are that efficiency at the database is not a big driving force.  But if you expect often to want to answer the question of what Lassie's loyalty to Timmy is, then there is much to be said for mapping the relationship as a `Map`.

Comment: Wait, I've seen it mentioned many times that one must not use `List` with `@ManyToMany`, because delete is very inefficient? I'm not sure I understand your first paragraph. Why would `Map<Person, Integer>` not be allowed? I've taken that idea from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75488588/4759176, in which they use a similar data structure.

Comment: You're right, it should be a `@ManyToMany` in relation to `Person`, but `@OneToMany` in relation to `DogPersonLoyalty` which would be 1 row in a `person_loyalty_mapping` table

Comment: Would there be any difference as to what table structure would be generated - between a `Map` and a `DogPersonLoyalty` approaches? If I were doing it in raw SQL, I'd think just one new table would suffice - `person_loyalty_mapping` with `dog_id`, `person_id`, `loyalty` columns

Comment: @parsecer, again, the `Map<Person, Integer>` does not work because when you map a relationship as a `Map`, the entities on the far side must appear as the *values* in the map, not the keys.  `Map<Person, Integer>` is simply not an option for the relationship mapping.

Comment: Again, because each related (`Dog`, `Person`) pair has its own loyalty score, you need an entity to hold that those scores.  All viable alternatives include a `DogPersonLoyalty` entity (by whatever name you like).  The main things to decide are the details of *how to map* the `Dog` <-> `DogPersonLoyalty` and `DogPersonLoyalty` <-> `Person` relationships.  This answer presents the mapping approach I would probably choose myself for the former, but there are other alternatives.

Comment: @parsecer, the same table structure (the one you describe) can support multiple mapping styles, including the one suggested in this answer.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. I apologize for my confusion, but why do they use an entity as a key and an Integer as a value in this answer, if it's not allowed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488429/persisting-a-map-where-the-key-is-an-entity-with-hibernate-and-spring/75488588#75488588. I also found this answer to a rather similar question, they use a map with entity-key and integer-value as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328788/4759176

Comment: @parsecer, the answer you're referring to presents an element collection, not a mapped relationship. Though they manifest similarly in your entity classes (and in particular, you can have a `Map` either way), there are significant semantic differences.  Since you used `@OneToMany` in both your alternatives, I supposed that a mapped relationship was indeed what you wanted. And I still think it probably is what you want.  But if you intended to ask about the differences between element collections and mapped relationships then that would have been a very different question.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear in my question. I used the `@OneToMany` by mistake, I was indeed intending to ask about `@ElementCollection` vs `@ManyToMany`. I tried to run both approaches through the database and made an edit to the post (with screenshots of the tables Hibernate created). I would greatly appreciate if you could elaborate on why is it that the mapped relationship would be what one would prefer to use over the `@ElementCollection`, in this case?